# Export .ePUB to text but somehow retain formatting

Tags: file-format, formatting

Is it possible to export an .ePUB document to .txt but also be able to retain the formatting of italicized and bold text? (For example, they can be in their own tags.)

Comment: Just unzip the epub to HTML  - or is HTML not what you are after. epub is just zipped HTML files

Comment: @Mark Sure I can do that, but I'll end up with a sea of tags. The answer below does what I want almost good enough.

Comment: .txt by definition is raw unformatted text. It cannot be formatted. Therefore, the question asks the impossible. It's easier to cut and paste from HTML output inside a browser and drop it into a text editor (for unformatted text) or MS Word (if you want formatted text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your epub book to a markdown/textile text file with [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download). Make sure to select markdown/textile, before running the epub to txt conversion.
(**Preferences > Output options > Text output > Formatting > markdown/textile**.)